# What does the clear key do on Apple's numpad?

Tags: keyboard

Apple has a [keyboard with a numpad](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB110LL/B/apple-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad). What does the <kbd>clear</kbd> key on the top left of the numpad do? Is it different from the <kbd>delete</kbd> key, if so, how is it different?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard OS X behaviour is for it to act similar to a <kbd>delete</kbd> key, but only when text is selected. It won't delete forwards or backwards like the standard <kbd>delete</kbd> keys. It also acts as a standard clear button in the Calculator app. This can vary by app however - in Excel for example, it functions identically to the <kbd>backspace</kbd> key.

Comment: It seems to do the same thing that Escape does in Calculator.

Answer (score 8):

I just found out by accident that it is also equivalent to clicking the cancel button on dialogs.